# The line integral of a vector field along two functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the vector field

$$\textbf{F}(x,y)=(x+y,x^2)$$

Compute the line integral of $\textbf{F}$ along the two curves $y=x$ and $y=x^3$ from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$.

I'm wondering if I did this correctly, because I don't have an answer sheet for this.

So first I let $F_1(x,y)=x+y$ and $F_2(x,y)=x^2$.

From Green's theorem we have that

$$\oint_{\partial R}\textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r}=\oint_{\partial R}F_1(x,y)dx+F_2(x,y)dy=\iint_R \left(\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}\right)dA=\iint_R(2x-1)dA$$

Our area $R$ is described by $x^3\leq y \leq x$ and $0\leq x \leq 1$.

Since the area is both $x$ and $y$-simple we can integrate in any order such that

$$\iint_R(2x-1)dA=\int_0^1\int_{x^3}^x(2x-1)dydx=\frac{1}{60} $$

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Yes; it looks fine to me

Comment: Isn’t the question asking for two separate line integrals? Not a single closed curve line integral

Comment: In any case, the line integral from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ along $y=x^3$ gives $\frac{27}{20}$, and back from $(1,1)$ to $(0,0)$ along $y=x$ gives $\frac{-4}{3}$, and their sum is $\frac{1}{60}$

Comment: How did you compute them individually @Loobear23 ? I am familiar with utilising Green's, but I don't think I've ever done them separately.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have misinterpreted the question.  I think they want you to compute two line integrals from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, one along the path $y=x$ and one along the path $y=x^3$.  The point of the question is that since $(x+y)\,\mathrm{d}x+x^2\,\mathrm{d}y$ is not an exact differential, you get different values.  That is, the integral depends on the path.

You have computed the the difference between these two integrals.  Since it's nonzero, that makes the same point.